# Questions on Distributed System Design - Scala

Tags: java, scala, distributed-system

I am going to implement sorting using many machines (distributed sorting).
I will code it with Scala. Because I do not have much experience with network programming, I need you guys help me to choose which library and method to make the communication between machines:

1/ How many machines can communicate using Message (this will be implement like case class in Scala)? Can I use ServerSocketChannel? Or should I build a TCP server for each machine? Do I need to serialize and de-serialize my object Message? If needed, can I use protobuf for doing that?

2/ How can I send data via network? Should I use java.io or java.nio?

I need to build my project using as less dependencies as possible.
Thank a lot.

Comment: The answer to most of these is "it depends" - on what you/r'e sorting, where the data is held, the volumes compared to the number of machines and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the simplest high level messaging library and since you have chosen Scala I would start with Akka which was designed with Scala in mind.

> How many machines can communicate using Message

You can communicate with every machine you can connect to e.g. the entire internet.

> If needed, can I use protobuf for doing that?

I suspect you don't need to, but yes.

> How can I send data via network?

I would use a messaging library

> Should I use java.io or java.nio?

The messaging library is likely to use these, but I wouldn't assume you need to use them directly.

> I am going to implement sorting using many machines (distributed sorting).

There are libraries designed for Scala which do this already. I would use one of those e.g. Spark or Hadoop.

Comment: I am not encouraged to use Hadoop, Spark, Akka. Any standard library?